# Is it possible to recover featured images after WordPress export/import

Tags: images, import, export

We recently moved all of the posts from a production site into a development site using the WordPress export/import routine and we realized that none of the features images came over.  A little research shows this is the default behavior for this process (which doesn’t make a bit of sense to me, but whatever).

There are some other complexities of this issue, but without making this request too difficult to answer, I’ll jump right to the question:  Is there any way to get the images moved over without redoing the export/import?